# Altering a redis index to remove stopwords

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm using RediSearch and I would like to remove all the stop words, I can read in the documentation that it says to set the `STOPWORDS` to 0 using the FT.CREATE command, however, I have an already created index I would like to modify to remove the stopwords, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the index has to be dropped and re-created with the STOPWORDS set to 0. I was using redis-om (for node) and I could turn off stopwords in the schema definition.

```js
import { Schema } from 'redis-om';

const something = new Schema({
    // ...options
}, {
  useStopWords: 'OFF'
})
```

The above example disables the stop words for the index, and if it is already created, it will be re-made by the lib itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Ace, been stuck on this. Thanks!